# Command to delete an entire method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vim, viemu

I am using viemu in VS 2010. Is there a reliable command to delete an entire method in C# source code?

Here are things I have tried:

- The movement commands `}` and `]]` are not smart enough to pick out a method. Although at times they do happen to grab the correct amount of text.
- From just within the method i can do `diB` which will delete the entire body of the method. That's not too bad, but then I'm left to delete the signature and outer brackets.
- If I move the cursor to the visibility modifier (ie `public`, `private`, etc) then do `d*`, it will kill the entire method if the next method has the same visibility.

Any vi/viemu experts have a way to do this?

Comment: Click the minus sign to the left of the method to collapse the method, highlight the entire collapsed method line, and press the Delete key.

Comment: That's not bad, you should make this an answer. You can also collapse the method with `CTRL+M,M`, then just do `dd` from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim, this is how I do it.  I'm not sure if viemu is compatible enough, but:

1. Move to the start of the method declaration (the accessibility modifier, etc).
2. Hit <kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode.
3. Position the cursor over the curly brace that starts the method body.
4. Hit <kbd>%</kbd> to move the cursor to the matching brace.
5. Hit <kbd>d</kbd> to remove everything that's selected.

It's not super-duper automatic or anything, but it works and is relatively easy to do once muscle memory kicks in.

Comment: move on first line of method then `^vf{%d`

Comment: Nice, that's much more compact and repeatable.  One could write a custom command to do that.

Comment: Your answer works fine in viemu, it doesn't look like shellholic's does though. I do like CTRL+M,M then dd, but that is Visual Studio specific and one reason for using viemu is to help me branch away from VS.

Comment: Actually I think I like go to the method signature, dd, d%. That does the trick every time and is pretty fast/simple.

Comment: @Matt: Assuming that you put your open curly braces on a separate line, yeah, that will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `zadd` to fold it and delete that fold (which will get the declaration too).

Another way to do it if you're inside the level of the method/if statement that you want to delete is `da{dd` which I find a little easier to type than some of the other suggestions.  It says to delete around the `{` bracket pair that the cursor is currently in, then `dd` to delete the remaining function declaration.

If you're nested inside control structures in a method, you can put a number before it to delete that many levels up.

Comment: (this works in vim, not sure about VS, don't have that, but these seem like pretty basic commands that it'd likely have)

Comment: This almost works in viemu, it leaves you one line off from the declaration, so basically it becomes `da{kdd`, assuming you have opening braces on their own line.

Answer (score 1):

`dap` (delete a paragraph) will work for simple methods which do not contain empty lines. For methods which do contain empty lines you will need to use `diBdap` (delete inner block followed by delete a paragraph). For easier use you can create a mapping in your rc file. ex: `:nmap <C-d> diBdap`

Comment: You might want to clarify what das is, otherwise this isn't helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate on das? I know `d` is the delete command, what type of movement is `as`? In viemu 2010 and gvim 7.3 for Windows `das` deletes a contiguous block of text, so if the method has empty lines in it, it will stop at the empty lines. If the method has no empty lines in it, `das` will delete it correctly.